# What is the default format of Date in spfx

Tags: spfx-webparts

I have make one column of Date and Time in Sharepoint, now I want to fetch this Date in my web part, how it can be done What will be its Datatype and format?

Answer (score 1):

I simply created an Interface/object in typescript. This object had the same structure as the list item. Among these I simply added a string datatype property which was used for the date type column from the list. See an example below:

```
export  interface IListItem {
    Id?: number;
    Title?: string;
    Date? : string;
}
```

Hope that helps!